# Перегрузка оператора @ в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, перегрузка-операторов

Столкнулся с необходимостью перегрузки оператора @ в Python. Требуется чтобы объекты класса M могли взаимодействовать друг с другом через оператор @.
Например:

```
a = M()
b = M()
a @ b
```

- требуемая сигнатура поведения.
  Подскажите, какой магический метод отвечает за этот оператор. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для поддержки оператора `@` нужно переопределить метод `__matmul__` (Или `__rmatmul__`, если нужно реализовать ситуацию, когда слева от `@` объект не поддерживающий оператор `@`, а справа объект нашего класса), для оператора `@=` - метод `__imatmul__`.

Пример:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A({})'.format(self.x)

    def __matmul__(self, other):
        print("Вызван метод __matmul__")
        if(isinstance(other, A)):
            return A(self.x * other.x)
        else:
            return A(self.x * other)

    def __rmatmul__(self, other):
        print("Вызван метод __rmatmul__")
        if(isinstance(other, A)):
            return A(self.x * other.x)
        else:
            return A(self.x * other)

    def __imatmul__(self, other):
        print("Вызван метод __imatmul__")
        return self @ other

a2 = A(2)

print(a2 @ A(3))
# Вывод:
# Вызван метод __matmul__
# A(6)
print(a2 @ 4)
# Вывод:
# Вызван метод __matmul__
# A(8)
print(5 @ a2)
# Вывод:
# Вызван метод __rmatmul__
# A(10)
a2 @= A(6)
print(a2)  # A(12)
# Вывод:
# Вызван метод __imatmul__
# Вызван метод __matmul__
# A(12)
```

Документация: [Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=matmul#emulating-numeric-types)

Answer (score 0):

Он называется [matmul](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__matmul__):

```
operator.matmul(a, b)
operator.__matmul__(a, b)

    Return a @ b.
```

Пример перекрытия:

```
class M:
    def __matmul__(self, other):
        print(self, other)

a = M()
b = M()
a @ b
# <__main__.M object at 0x00000281C3A07860> <__main__.M object at 0x00000281C5935E10>
```